# Should we add the stuff about asking questions in the imperative mode and showing your work to the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

Gently exhorting question-askers to mind the two above guidelines (not asking questions by posting in the imperative mode, and showing your work when asking) seems to have penetrated pretty well, and become a norm in our community, so I thought it might be useful to add that stuff to the FAQ or as a reminder in the question pane, before it reaches the comment stage.  Right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that is a very good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Diamond moderators can edit the top part of the faq.

The How to Ask pane does already include this information, for the most part:

[image]

If you would like that to say something different, let me know what it is and I can change it.

(but good luck getting people to read.. sigh.)